# Icon Disa on status bar

Tags: notification-icons, 8.0-oreo

Is there a way to remove the Disa's icon on the status bar?
It stays and when I scroll down to see, it says "Everything is running smoothly".

[image: disa not]

Can we remove this and have this icon only when I receive message?

Comment: I have added a screenshot to improve clarity

Answer (score 2):

According to [Disa FAQ](https://plus.google.com/108860290035481784523/posts/WWzKkgKbWZ5) that's foreground feature.

> The persistent notification is created by the **Foreground** setting,
>   found in the General tab of Disa's settings. If your device is fairly
>   new and has plenty of free memory then this setting does not need to
>   be enabled. If you choose to disable it remember to restart Disa for
>   the change to take effect.
>
> The persistent notification was enabled by default for older devices
>   which cannot run Disa in the background without it. However, if you
>   feel that everything is working fine, i.e. you are not seeing the
>   splash screen every time you start up Disa and/or you have no delayed
>   notifications or missed messages, then you can turn this **off** in
>   Settings.

Go to the General tab and then **untick** Foreground. You may need to restart Disa before the notification goes away;

[image]

Note: *Some devices (EMUI, OxygenOS​ and devices without Google Play Services) get delayed messages without this feature enabled.*

[Credits:"Disa everything is running smoothly" won't clear](https://www.reddit.com/r/Disa/comments/70bf1e/disa_everything_is_running_smoothly_wont_clear/?st=jcx6n0zr&sh=a411b142)